# Strapi dynamic zone - display image in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, strapi, gatsby-image

I am using Strapi with Gatsby and having difficulty rendering images within a dynamic zone. I am using:

- Strapi 3.6.2
- Gatsby 3.5.1
- gatsby-source-strapi 1.0.0
- gatsby-plugin-image 1.5.0
- gatsby-plugin-sharp 3.5.0
- gatsby-transformer-sharp 3.5.0

Top level image fields found directly in collection types can be queried easily with GraphQL to return `gatsbyImageData`, see thumbnail field as an example:

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiPage {
    nodes {
      Title
      Body
      thumbnail {
        localFile {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, in the query above `Body` is a dynamic zone field with dozens of selectable components, many of which contain image fields. The data returned for Body is standard JSON data meaning the image fields don't have the required `gatsbyImageData`, see example response:

```
    "Body": [
    {
        "PrimaryImage": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Test Image",
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "width": 338,
            "height": 260,
            "formats": {
                "thumbnail": {
                    "name": "thumbnail_Test Image",
                    "hash": "thumbnail_testimage_c3ced5807d",
                    "ext": ".png",
                    "mime": "image/png",
                    "width": 203,
                    "height": 156,
                    "size": 78.25,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_testimage_c3ced5807d.png"
                }
            },
            "hash": "testimage_c3ced5807d",
            "ext": ".png",
            "mime": "image/png",
            "size": 154.53,
            "url": "/uploads/testimage_c3ced5807d.png",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "created_at": "2021-04-19T14:20:38.086Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-19T14:20:38.133Z",
            "localFile___NODE": "c5a14269-31a2-505a-b2ff-8251e6ca5051"
        },
        "strapi_component": "sections.task-row"
}
    }]
```

`<StaticImage />` doesn't accept a dynamic `src` so I cannot use the `url` field. I have to use `<GatsbyImage/>` which requires `gatsbyImageData` object.

Is there any way to modify the query OR use the fields that are available to get images rendering with `<GatsbyImage />`

---

**Update**: A Strapi developer has [confirmed this is not currently possible](https://twitter.com/remidej/status/1395305940073787392).
My best solution at the moment is unfortunately not to use `gatsby-plugin-image` and use `<img src={imagepath} />` instead
where `imagepath` references the image directly through a running instance of Strapi e.g. http://localhost:1337/uploads/test-image.png

Alternatively, you could include the copying of images from your Strapi folder to your Gatsby folder into your build process so you can reference them locally in Gatsby if you'd rather keep the environments separate. *(may be slow for lots of images)*

Still hoping for a better solution :)

Comment: how you are getting just the thumbnail, in my case i'm getting thumbnail, small, large, is it possible to just get the original image ? not to generate the thumbnails,small, large ?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic zones in Strapi we need to use  *spread operators(...)* followed by *on* then *__typename* of the Component

Eg:

```
 DynamicZoneName{
...on ComponentName{
            // component values
                   }
   ...on AnotherComponentName{
            // component values
                   }

      }
```

In your case the new query should be similar to:

```
query MyQuery {
          allStrapiPage {
            nodes {
              Title
              Body{
                 ... on ComponentPrimaryImage{
                       formats,
                       url,
                       name,
                       id,
                       //any other values you want
                    }
                }
              thumbnail {
                localFile {
                  childImageSharp {
                    gatsbyImageData
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

**Steps**

- Open Graphql url fro strapi application.
- Write your old query
- Within parenthesis of Dynamic Zone write

  ```
   ... on
  ```
- Open the auto Finish to get linked **__typename** of dynamic zones
- Refer to initial code block to proceed ahead

Refer [this](https://strapi.io/blog/creating-strapi-dynamic-zone-in-nuxtjs-app) article to understand dynamic zones implementation in graphql

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I believe your solution is for older versions of `Strapi` and `gatsby-source-strapi`. Please see this article: https://strapi.io/blog/introducing-the-new-gatsby-source-strapi-plugin which announces native support for Dynamic Zones. Remi a Strapi developer has confirmed that `gatsby-plugin-image` is not currently supported in Dynamic Zones.